# unique pairs or combinations from a vector

Tags: r

Where am I going wrong with my function.

I am trying to create a function which will count all the unique pairs in a vector, say I have the following input:

```
ar <- c(10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 50)
```

The number of unique pairs is `20 = 1`, `30 = 1` so I can just sum these up and the total number of unique pairs is `2`.

However everything I am trying is creating `30` as having 2 unique pairs (since `30` occurs 3 times in the vector.

```
n <- 9
ar <- c(10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 50)

CountThePairs <- function(n, ar){
  for(i in 1:length(ar)){
    sum = ar[i] - ar[]
    pairs = length(which(sum == 0))
  }
  return(sum)
}

CountThePairs(n = NULL, ar)
```

Is there an easier way of doing this? I prefer the base R version but interested in package versions also.

Comment: `length(with(rle(ar), unique(values[lengths >= 2])))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler way using `floor` and `table` form base R -

```
ar <- c(10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 50)

sum(floor(table(ar)/2))

[1] 2
```

**Example 2** - Adding one more `30` to vector so now there are 2 pairs of `30` -

```
ar <- c(10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 50)

sum(floor(table(ar)/2))

[1] 3
```

If 2 `30` pairs count as one "unique" pair then original solution by @tmfmnk was correct -

```
sum(table(ar) >= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply` on the unique values of the vector to return a logical vector if that value is repeated. The sum of that logical value is then the number of unique pairs.

```r
ar <- c(10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 50)

is_pair <- sapply(unique(ar), function(x) length(ar[ar == x]) > 1)
sum(is_pair)
#[1] 2
```

I'm not sure what behaviour you want if there are four 30's - does this count as one unique pair still or is it now two? If the latter, you would need a slightly different solution:

```r
n_pair <- sapply(unique(ar), function(x) length(ar[ar == x]) %/% 2)
sum(n_pair)
#[1] 2
```